# I wish to put this condition in a more sargable way

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql, sql-server-2017

In my sql server 2017 standard CU 20 there is a very often excuted query that has this awful condition:

```
AND F.progressive_invoice % @numberofservicesInstalled = @idService
```

Is there a mathematical way to put it in a more convenient way for sql server?

The query lasts from 240 to 500 ms
Can you help me to do better? Please

Comment: maybe is sufficient to put all the operations to the right of the equlas (=)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you think is particularly *awful* here?

Is this query performing badly? Are you sure, that this condition is responsible?

This `%` is the [modulo operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/modulo-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

```
SELECT  13 % 5 => Remainder is 3
```

--This is roughly the same your code is doing:

```
DECLARE @Divisor INT=5; --Switch this value
DECLARE @CompareRemainder INT=3;
SELECT CASE WHEN 13 % @Divisor = @CompareRemainder THEN 'Remainder matches variable' ELSE 'no match' END;
```

Your line of code will tell the engine to compute a integer division of `F.progressive_invoice` and the variable `@numberofservicesInstalled`, then pick the remainder. This computation's result is compared to the variable `@idService`.

As this computation must be done for each value, an index will not help here...

I do not think, that this can be put *more sargable*.

**UPDATE**

In a comment you suggest, that it might help to change the code *behind* the equal operator. No this will not help.

I tried to think of a senseful meaning of this... Is the *number of a service* (or - as the variable suggests - its `id`) somehow *hidden* in the invoice number?

execution plan and row estimation:

The engine will see, that this must be computed for all rows. It would help to enforce any other filter **before** you have to do this. But you do not show enough. The line of code we see is just one part of a condition...

Indexes and statistics will surely play their roles too...

Comment: the query plan overestimates a lot the values returned just in this condition, maybe if you can put the operation to the right of the = operator the outcome should be better

Comment: the query is inherited by programmers and fortunately is in a stored procedure , but I can't exactly figure what is it for. this are the fields explained: F.progressive_invoice  is a number wich is progressive on the invoices , numberofservicesInstalled is the number of services on the client, idService is the id of the service.

Comment: tomorrow I can share you the plan

Comment: @GabrieleD'Onufrio what means "progressive" exactly? What is the maximum value of @idService? What the max for @numberofservicesInstalled? Looks like a strange way to hide two values in one column...

Comment: progressive means sequential ... idservice is generally 1 but can be also 2 , numberofservicesInstalled is 0-1-2

Comment: @GabrieleD'Onufrio, well that is a strange way to encode the service I'd **into* the invoice number, isn't it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217122/discussion-between-gabriele-donufrio-and-shnugo).

Answer (score 1):

The short answer to your direct question is no. You cannot rearrange this expression to make it a sargable predicate. At least, not with a construct which is finite and agnostic of the possible values of @numberofservicesinstalled.